# RuntimeExtension.class -- What does the ".class" mean?

Tags: java, junit

I've read the docs for the Junit ExpectedException class, and the parameter for the .expect() method seems to be implemented strangely in all the examples I've studies. When you pass in the expected exception type, it has a .class extension that doesn't appear to be a method of any kind.

Can someone please explain this syntax? Thank you. Example code is below:

```
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

public void testPlusException() {
    thrown.expect(RuntimeException.class);
    Vector testVector = vector1.plus(vector3);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling .class on a type gets the class object of the particular type. You can read more about the specifics here.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html

Comment: Thank you. I knew about .getClass() but had no idea about this way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not mentioned in the Java documentation for the [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class, all classes derived from `Object` have a `public static Class<T> class` member that stores the runtime type of said object.

It's also what gets returned when you call `getClass()` on an object, keeping in mind that all methods in Java are [virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function).

Comment: Technically, it's not a member.  You can't use `class` in every syntax where you can use other static members, and the `getFields()` method of `Class` won't return `class` as one of the members.

Comment: Also it's not really part of `Object` because you can do `boolean.class`